# Changing position of selector programmatically in Pickerview when it is initially loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

How can we change the position of the selector in the Pickerview when it is loaded. For example, I want to make row 3 initially selected when it is loaded. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[pickerView selectRow:selectedIndex inComponent:0 animated:YES];`

animated with cause the selector to start at 0 and swing to `selectedIndex`, animated at NO will simply cause the picker to appear with the selected index.